# Why do I have to use \indent twice?

Tags: indentation

**Edit** After fruitful answers I edited the question.

In order to make an indentation **after Theorem** I have to write

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section*{The very first question}
Start
\begin{theorem}
Some theorem
\end{theorem}
\indent \indent Something
\end{document}
```

If I use

```
\indent Something
```

then I do not get an indentation.

**Question.** Is it normal that I have to write `\indent` twice?

Comment: I think maybe you want `\usepackage{indentfirst}` and no `\indent`s at all. After equations, try leave an empty line before the text.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No. I use it in fact and still I have to use \indent twice. I haven't wrote it above for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Then something else is up, if I add that package to your code, and remove the indents, I get indentation.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I know, but somethimes I would like ot make an additional indentation after an equation. In such situation package indentfirst does not help

Comment: So `indentfirst` works after `\section` for you as well? If you want to start a new paragraph (which is what the indentation signifies) after an equation, add a paragraph break, that is, add an empty line after `\end{equation}`.

Comment: You should just leave a blank line before each paragraph...

Comment: In future, please put the actual question in the question and provide enough information. Excluding irrelevant information is good and sometimes you go too far by mistake and that's okay. But pretending you want (a) when really you want (b), or (a), (b) and (c) doesn't help anybody - including you

Comment: @Au101 i will keep this hint in mind. Sorry for trouble.

Comment: You should never need `\indent` at all, definitely never three times.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I promise that I won't use \indent again.

Comment: ohh you will, everyone does:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just leave a blank line after `\end{theorem}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section*{The very first question}
Start
\begin{theorem}
Some theorem
\end{theorem}

Something

\end{document}
```

[image]

You get indentation even without a blank line if you add

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
```

(which I would recommend).

The default of LaTeX is not to indent the paragraph following a `list` based environment (and those declared by `\newtheorem` are based on `list`) if no blank line intervenes. This is very useful for environments such as `enumerate` or `itemize` that can well be used “in a paragraph”.

With `amsthm`, this behavior is changed for the environments declared by `\newtheorem`, under the assumption that a theorem is never “in a paragraph”.

Note that, without `indentfirst`, leaving a blank line after a section title will have no effect, because it's a different situation than `list` based environments. By default the indentation after a sectional title is suppressed “forever”, so `\indent` does nothing (but another one would add a space similar to `\hspace*{\parindent}`). With `indentfirst` the behavior is similar: you get indentation after a sectional title independently of a blank line.

I usually suggest *always* leaving a blank line after a sectional title and two of them before it, so as to “isolate” the title in the typescript for better searching.

Comment: Great. It is precisely what I wanted. I find it strange that one "Enter" makes such a difference.

Comment: i will use this recommended version. Thx one more time.

Comment: @FallenApart A clear line is how you tell TeX you're starting a new paragraph. And that's what the indentation means in the output. If you want TeX to start a new paragraph, you have to tell it that. Trying to manually add space - which is TeX's job - is not the way to go.

Comment: @Au101 Thank you for explenation. I though that double "Enter" is treated equaly as "Space". Thanks to your explenation I start to understand why on Math.SE I use double "Enter".

Comment: @FallenApart *Single* enter is treated equally as 'space' double enter is very different

Comment: @Au101 Thank you for making effort in explaining so basic things to me. I feel bad for not knowing such stuff, but also I have feeling that this community is very understanding. I will try not to overuse it.

Answer (score 5):

The explanation below also holds for the updated question.

LaTeX suppresses the indentation of the first paragraph after a section title by default. If you want to have these paragraphs indented, then package `indentfirst` is your friend:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}

\section*{The very first question}
Something
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Why `\indent\indent` works:

The first `\indent` starts a new paragraph and sets a box for the indentation. Also, the token register `\everypar` is executed. The `\section` code sets this token register to cancel the indentation of the first paragraph. This is done by `\setbox0\lastbox` inside a group. Now, we have horizontal mode without indentation. Then, the second `\indent` just sets the indentation box without calling `\everypar`, because we are already in horizontal mode.

Comment: I have edited the question. Previously I simplified the question too much.

Answer (score 3):

I take it that you would like to have paragraphs that immediately follow section headers to be indented (presumably in the amount of `\parindent`). If that's the case, you needn't (and shouldn't) be typing `\indent` manually. Instead, simply load the [indentfirst](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/indentfirst) package in the preamble.

Should you really want to type these indentation instructions by hand, the LaTeX way to do it would be to write

```
\hspace{\parindent}
```

rather than `\indent` (or `\indent\indent`)

Comment: I would like to have additional indentation after some equation.

Comment: @FallenApart - In that case, type `\hspace{\parindent}`. Or, better still, simply leave a blank line between the end of the display-math environment in question and the next paragraph.

Comment: don't you need `\hspace*`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Both methods appears to work equally well for a small sample document I've drawn up.

Comment: I lied previously. I actually want to get an indent after some theorem (not equation).

Comment: @FallenApart - `\hspace{\parindent}` works equally well after a `theorem`-like environment. Or, as always when wishing to start a new paragraph in a LaTeX document, simply leave a blank line between the theorem and the next text paragraph...

Comment: Sorry. I just simplified question too much. I thought that my original question would be enought to make an answer, but the problem occured to be more complex.